# Finitely generated module and finitely generated algebra over a Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

I am given that $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $S \subseteq R[x]$ is a ring. How can I prove that if $R[x]$ is a finitely generated $S$-module then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra.

I am thinking of using Artin -Tate lemma and induction but not sure of how to write the proof for the induction part. Could someone please walk me through the proof. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $ R = \mathbf Z[i] $ and $ S = \mathbf Z[x] $ is a counterexample. Perhaps you meant to add a condition that $ R \subset S $?

Comment: $R[x]$ is an $S$-module and $S$ is and $R$-algebra.